# Webcam partially doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, skype, webcam, zoom-meeting

My no-name USB webcam doesn't work in Windows 7 in Zoom and Skype. It works perfectly in a web-based test website.

In Device Manager it's properly recognised as "HD WebCam" under Imaging Devices, without any error.

Zoom and Skype themselves DO in fact know that there's something there, because they do recognise the webcam's built-in microphone under "audio settings" (no other microphone on this PC). But still, "No camera detected".

For Windows 10 there's ample advice online regarding granting permission to Skype and Zoom to use the camera. But Windows 7 doesn't have similar privacy settings in Control Panel, as far as I can see. When I look at the zoom.exe file, it seems to have full permissions. When I run Zoom as Administrator: no difference.

The webcam works fine with Zoom and Skype on a different Windows 10 PC.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any OEM USB drivers installed.  In my personal experience I found those to interfere with web cameras

Comment: There are no more fixes or feature updates for Windows 7. If you must use Windows 7, you might consider a better camera.